# Delete all characters using sed except missing values

Tags: awk, sed

I have a text file as below:

**$cat text.txt**

```
 An = 2, 3, 4, 5, 0.3
      3, 3, 4, 5, 0.5
      3, 4, 5, 6, -19
      4, 5, 5, 5, 10E+10
```

I would like to delete all the characters except the missing values like 10E+10

Desire output is

**$Outfile.txt**

```
2 3 3 4 0.3
3 3 4 5 0.5
4 4 5 5 -19
5 5 6 5 10E+10
```

My below script is deleting all the characters including E

**$script.sh**

```
sed 's/[A-Z]//g;s/=//g;s/}//g;s/[a-z]//g;s/,//g' text.txt
```

Comment: When you say `missing values` - do you mean `numeric values`?

Answer (score 4):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    {
        gsub(/,/," ")
        out = sep = ""
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            if ( $i == $i+0 ) {
                out = out sep $i
                sep = OFS
            }
        }
        print out
    }
' text.txt
2 3 4 5 0.3
3 3 4 5 0.5
3 4 5 6 -19
4 5 5 5 10E+10
```

That `if ( $i == $i+0 )` is the idiomatic way to test for a value being a number (which I think is what you're asking for) since only a numeric value equals itself before and after adding `0` to it.

Answer (score 2):

```
tr -d '[A-DF-Za-z,=]' < text.txt | sed 's/^  *//'
```

produces

```
2 3 4 5 0.3
3 3 4 5 0.5
3 4 5 6 -19
4 5 5 5 10E+10
```

You can get similar results deleting character ranges with sed, and have a 2nd pass (as above) to remove the leading spaces.

```
sed 's/[A-DF-Za-z,=][A-DF-Za-z,=]*//g;s/^  *//'
```

The character range `[A-DF-Za-z,=]` matches any alpha character except `E` as well as `,` and `=`. If we just put `*` after it immediately we'd be saying zero or more of `[A-D...]`, so we need to repeat the range so we match at least one of `[A-D...]` and then zero-or-more of the preceding. Using `g` of course globalizes the substitution per line.

We anchor the 2nd substitution at the front of the line with `/^` and again, we need 2 space chars so that the `*` zero-or-more token will require at least one space at the front of the line to match.

You might want to use `[A-DF-Za-df-z,=]` as your range to allow for the possibility that some software will output lower case chars as part of the exponent.

There are of course possible inputs that will cause this to fail, but if your data source is well organized and consistent then this can work.

There are also home-brew awk functions that can determine `isNum()` and that would probably be more bullet proof than above. But that,... is a separate question (-;

Answer (score 2):

it's not elegant but gets it done :

```
 echo ' An = 2, 3, 4, 5, 0.3
      3, 3, 4, 5, 0.5
      3, 4, 5, 6, -19
      4, 5, 5, 5, 10E+10' |
```

> ```
> mawk 'BEGIN {   FS = "^[^=]+=|, |[ \t\f-\r]+)"
>                 RS = "^$"
>            _ = ORS = "" } gsub("\n[^0-9]+","\n", 
>              $!(NF = NF)) + sub("^[^0-9]+",_)^_'
> ```

```
2 3 4 5 0.3
3 3 4 5 0.5
3 4 5 6 -19
4 5 5 5 10E+10
```

Answer (score 2):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `text.txt` content be

```
 An = 2, 3, 4, 5, 0.3
      3, 3, 4, 5, 0.5
      3, 4, 5, 6, -19
      4, 5, 5, 5, 10E+10
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="-?[0-9][0-9.Ee+\\-]*"}{$1=$1;print}' text.txt
```

gives output

```
2 3 4 5 0.3
3 3 4 5 0.5
3 4 5 6 -19
4 5 5 5 10E+10
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field is zero-or-one (`?`) minus sign followed by one digit followed by zero-or-more (`*`) of following characters: digits, dot, uppercase E, lowercase e, minus sign (which needs to be escaped to avoid treatment as part of range). I do `$1=$1` to trigger string rebuilt, then I `print` it. **Warning**: I only tested with provided sample, if more complicated cases are present in actual data, please test code carefully before deploying it.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 2):

GNU AWK

```
gsub(".*= |^ +|,","")
```

- `.*=` remove any until `=`
- `^ +` remove leading blanks
- `,` remove any comma

---

```
$ echo ' An = 2, 3, 4, 5, 0.3
      3, 3, 4, 5, 0.5
      3, 4, 5, 6, -19
      4, 5, 5, 5, 10E+10'|awk 'gsub(".*= |^ +|,","")'
2 3 4 5 0.3
3 3 4 5 0.5
3 4 5 6 -19
4 5 5 5 10E+10
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of your code?

Answer (score 2):

When using the search and replace command `s` of `sed`, it might not be easy to handle all possible situations encountered in hte input.

Maybe you could try this:

```
sed 's/[^-.0-9 E+]//g;
     s/^[^ ][^ ]*-[^0-9]//g;
     s/[^ ]-[^0-9]//g;
     s/^[^0-9][^0-9]*E//;
     s/[^0-9][^0-9]*E//g;
     s/  */ /g;
     s/^  *//g' text.txt
```

... better to test with many different inputs...

--

A *real solution* would be to iterate over the elements of each line in order to select the numbers to print.

At time of writing the `awk` scripts proposed in other answers should be the more efficient (but less fun) than the below `bash` lines.

`printf "%f"` generates an erred exit status when the parameter is not a number. This is working ok with scientific notation of a number: e.g. 10E+19

Fun isn't it?

```
sed 's/[^-.0-9 E+]//g;s/  */ /g;s/^  *//g' text.txt |\
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    one_number_printed=no
    for element in $line ; do
      if printf "%f" "${element}" >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
        if [[ "${one_number_printed}" == no ]] ; then
          one_number_printed=yes
          printf "%s" "${element}"
        else 
          printf " %s" "${element}"
        fi
      fi
    done
    if [[ "${one_number_printed}" != no ]] ; then
      printf "\n"
    fi
  done
```

**Output**

```
2 3 4 5 0.3
3 3 4 5 0.5
3 4 5 6 -19
4 5 5 5 10E+10
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'G;:a;s/^(-?[0-9]+((E\+|\.)[0-9]+)?,?)(.*\n.*)/\4\1/;ta;s/.(.*\n)/\1/;ta
        y/,/ /;s/.//' file
```

Append a newline to the end of the line as a delimiter.

At the start of the line match a possible  negative sign, followed by one or digits, followed by a possible mantissa, followed by a possible comma and append it to the end of the line and repeat.

Otherwise, remove the next character and repeat.

When all matches fail, replace commas by spaces and remove the introduced newline.

An alternative:

```
sed -E 'y/@/ /;s/-?[0-9]+((E\+|\.)[0-9]+)?,?/\n@&\n/g
        s/^[^@].*//mg;s/@|\n//g;y/,/ /' file
```

Prepared the ground by replacing any `@`'s. An `@` at the start of a line will represent what follows to the end of the line is match.

Prepend a newline and an `@` at the front of a match (see above) and append a newline following a match.

Using multiline substitution, remove any lines that do not begin with an `@`.

Remove all `@`'s and newlines.

Translate commas to spaces.

N.B. Both solutions use the same methodology. Erect some scaffolding, solve an easier problem and then remove the scaffolding. In the first case, newlines do not exist in vanilla sed and therefore can by used as a delimiter without fear of false positives. In the second case, the `@`'s are replaced and later used as a match flag.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed 's/[An=]/ /g;s/,//g' text.txt
```